# array with a for in JavaScript not change every var

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

Hi I have some trouble with an array with a for in JavaScript. Let's have a look:

```
var Villes = [
  ['Versailles+France', 'upr2.png'],
  ['Paris+France', 'upr5.png'],
  ['Bruxelle+Belgique', 'upr4.png'],
  ['Manchester+Angleterre', 'upr1.png'],
  ['Monaco+Monaco', 'upr3.png']
];

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.225453,2.219238),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  for (var i = 0; i < Villes.length; i++) {
    var ville = Villes[i];
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': ville[0]}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: results[0].geometry.location,map: map,icon: ville[1]});
        alert(ville[1] + status);
      } else {
        alert("Geocode n'a pas fonctionner. Erreur: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My Map comes with all my marker but the icon never change like `ville[1]` is a static call to `upr3.png` I'm not used to JS and it's the first time I see that.

Comment: Please format your code before posting..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `geocode` call is asynchronous, which means that you will loop through all the places and send requests, then the responses will arrive. At that time you have already run through the loop, and the `ville` variable has the value of the last place.

Put a function expression around the code in the loop, so that each iteration has its own copy of the variable:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Villes.length; i++) {

  (function(ville){

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': ville[0]}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: results[0].geometry.location,map: map,icon: ville[1]});
        alert(ville[1] + status);
      } else {
        alert("Geocode n'a pas fonctionner. Erreur: " + status);
      }
    });

  })(Villes[i]);

}
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer, I'm really not usual with the async effects ;-)

Answer (score 1):

By the time the callback you give to `geocode` is called, `i` has the value of end of loop.

The usual generic solution is to protect it by an immediately called function expression :

```
for (var i = 0; i < Villes.length; i++) {
     (function(ville){
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': ville[0]}, function(results, status)
           ...
        });
     })(Villes[i]);
}
```

As the scope of a variable is the function in which it is declared, this makes the new variable `ville` immune to the variation of the loop.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer, I'm really not usual with the async effects ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ville` is not an array, so by the time the for loop finishes, `ville` only has the value of the last item in your initial array (png3). You need call the function right after setting the value to `ville`

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer, I'm really not usual with the async effects ;-)